# Missing References Devexpress VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, devexpress

I really need help. I remember removing a reference, completely unrelated to DevExpress, from my project a few days ago and I think it's completely broke my project. I have 92~ errors relating to devexpress items. I can't definatively say what caused this mess, but my entire project has broken. Here's a snap shot below.

[image: Error List]

But I appear to have all the references I need:

[image]

Everything relating to DevExpress is highlighted as errors.

[image]

I've tried re-installing DevExpress and Visual Studio, I *can* create a new project and work with DevExpress without any issues, so I feel like I'm missing something in my current project.

**The designer code:**

```
   <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class EngineerCallOut
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(EngineerCallOut))
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblStoreType = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.comboStoreType = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit()
        Me.lblPriority = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.comboPriority = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit()
        Me.PopupMenu1 = New DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu(Me.components)
        Me.StatusStrip1 = New System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip()
        Me.lblStatus = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel()
        Me.lblInitials = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblIncident = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblEquipment = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblDescription = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblDisclaimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.txtEquip = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtRef = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtInitials = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtDisclaimer = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.LogTime = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit()
        Me.lblLogDate = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblStore = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblOpenHours = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label13 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.txtOpeningHours = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtStore = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.txtDesc = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.btnSettings = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit()
        Me.PictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.btnClear = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit()
        Me.btnPreview = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit()
        Me.btnExport = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit()
        Me.lblHardwareETA = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblSoftware = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label16 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Panel2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.btnPreviewRetry = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit()
        Me.btnPreviewConfirm = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit()
        Me.txtPreview = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.comboTemplateType = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit()
        Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        CType(Me.comboStoreType.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.comboPriority.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PopupMenu1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.StatusStrip1.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.LogTime.Properties.CalendarTimeProperties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.LogTime.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.btnSettings.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.btnClear.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.btnPreview.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.btnExport.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.Panel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.Panel2.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.btnPreviewRetry.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.btnPreviewConfirm.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.comboTemplateType.Properties, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
        Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(111, 57)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(229, 20)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Label1.Text = "Engineer Call Out Template"



        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the same name in reference and add it again.
2. If you do not have the DevExpress.dll, you can search by Google and added it to reference and to bin folder.
3. Check your framework if it except this reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the form where shows error.
2. Just peek `devexpresstools` form toolbox.like xtrabutton.
3. Then if you dont want this tool then you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple way, just uninstall the DevExpress, remove the unregistered dll as suggested by follow.

1. Open PowerShell/CMD

   and type in

   ```
   ToolboxCreator.exe /INI:toolboxcreator.ini /LOG:CreatorLog.log /PATH "%PROGRAMFILES%/DevExpress 2010.2/Components/Sources/DevExpress.DLL/
   ```

   and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. If it does not work, then remove the registry suggested from

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages\{2c298b35-07da-45f1-96a3-be55d91c8d7a}\Toolbox
   ```